# If $a \in A$ maps to a unit of $A/\operatorname{nil}(A)$, then $a$ is a unit of $A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $A$ be a ring, $I \subset \operatorname{nil}(A)$ an ideal made up
>   of nilpotent elements.  Show that if $a \in A$ maps to a unit of $A/I$,
>   then $a$ is a unit of $A$.

I tried this: If $ab = 1 - x$ with $x^n=0$.  How can I prove that
$$
ab(1+x+\ldots+x^{n-1}) = 1 \, ?
$$

Hope someone could help me please. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**
\begin{align*}
(1-x)(1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^{n-1}) = 1 &+ x + x^2 + \cdots + x^{n-1}\\
&- x - x^2 - \cdots - x^{n-1} - x^n = \cdots
\end{align*}