# Let $I$ be an ideal of nilpotent elements. Show that if $a$ maps to a unit in $A/I$, then $a$ is a unit in $A$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification

This is the same as [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2195935/if-a-in-a-maps-to-a-unit-of-a-operatornamenila-then-a-is-a-unit-of), though a solution was never given, and my approach is different than the hint.

It's also the first exercise in *Commutative Ring Theory* by Matsumura.

Let $A$ be a (commutative) ring and $I \subset \operatorname{nil}(A)$ an ideal made up of nilpotent elements; if $a\in A$ maps to a unit of $A/I$ then $a$ is a unit of $A$.

Attempt:

Since $a$ maps to a unit in $A/I$, we have that for $a+I$ there exists some coset $a'+I$ such that $(a+I)(a'+I)=1+I$. By coset multiplication, we have $(aa')+I=1+I$, which implies that $aa'= 1+i$ for some $i\in I$. Since $i$ is nilpotent, there exists $n>0$ such that $i^n=0$. If $i=0$, we are done. Otherwise, we have that $n \geq 2$ so we can do the following:

\begin{align*}
aa' &= 1+ i\\
aa'i^{n-1}&=(1+i)i^{n-1}\\
aa'i^{n-1} &= i^{n-1}+0\\
aa'i^{n-1} &= i^{n-1}\\
aa' &= 1,
\end{align*}

showing that $a$ is indeed a unit in $A$.

Is this correct?

P.S. I would guess that there is an easier method, but I wanted to try to proceed directly from the definition and work with cosets in the quotient ring.

Comment: How did you deduce $aa'=1$ in the last step? Remember, in a ring you can't in general divide by elements. Also, note that your solution can't be correct, because it would actually tell us that any representative of the coset $(a+I)^{-1}$ is an inverse of $a$, which can't be true, because an inverse is unique.

Comment: @Mark In my head I multiplied both sides by $i^{-(n-1)}$, but now I see that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
    aa' &=1+i\\
    aa'-1&=i\\
    (aa'-1)^n&=i^n\\
    (aa'-1)^n&=0\\
    \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}(aa')^k(-1)^{n-k}&=0\\
    a\left(\sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k}a^{k-1}a'^k(-1)^{n-k}\right)&=(-1)^{n+1}\\
    a\left(\sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k}a^{k-1}a'^k(-1)^{1-k}\right)&=1
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Since the Jacobson radical contains every nil ideal, every element of $I$ is [quasiregular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiregular_element).

So, if $ab\equiv 1\mod I$, it amounts to $ab-1=i$ for some $i\in I$. By quasiregularity $i+1=ab$ is invertible in $R$. The same can be said for $ba$ and then you can conclude that $a$ is invertible in $R$ too.

---

If you want something a little concrete with how nilpotence is connected, the question about why [$1-x$ is a unit if $x$ is nilpotent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119904/units-and-nilpotents) is one of the most-asked questions in the ring-theory tag!  You can use this instead of quasiregularity to see why $ab$ is a unit.

Comment: The question is about commutative rings.

Comment: @Mark This proof includes commutative rings so... ?  (Maybe I should mention that I like giving proofs that apply even if the ring isn't commutative, if they are available.)

Comment: Anyway, this answer is correct, though maybe goes a bit too far. In the last sentence OP asked for a proof using just the definitions. (otherwise, in the commutative case you can also easily prove it using prime ideals)

Comment: @Mark I'm willing to include a link to the reason why 1+nilpotent is a unit because it's been beaten to death on math.se over the years.  It seems like the simplest analogue.